# Get title from link, PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm trying to get the title from a link - which I already have identified, it is just the last bit with retrieving the title from the same link.

To find the right link I use this code:

```
$html->find('a[href=http://mylink.se']');
```

But I also want the title from this link. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser, which is not clear in your question, you could do

```
$link = $html->find('a[href=http://mylink.se]', 0); //As the OP pointed out in comments, you need to select the first element
$title = $link->title
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes I use "PHP Simple HTML DOM parser" as stated in the title.

Although I don't get it right. Don't understand your code exactly. I've tried "$title = $link->title" and "$title = $link->find('title')". Those doesn't work.

Comment: To get the "title" of your link, as per your original post, do the following:
`$html->find('a[href=http://mylink.se'])->plaintext;`

Comment: Thanks again for answer. Although you misunderstood it. I don't want the anchor text, I want the title (<a href="url" title="**title**">Anchor text</a>). How do I solve that?

Comment: In that case, simply doing $link->title should work. Can you edit your OP with full code or minimal reproduction so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: My code is the following:
`$find = $html->find('a[href=http://mylink.se']');
$title = $find->title;
echo $title;`

Comment: I mean the whole thing, including where you got the $html from. Edit your original post with it.

Comment: Ahh yes! Found the solution. This code work: `$html->find('a[href=http://mylink.se']', 0)->title;`